# Criar formulário dinâmico com tags

Tags: javascript, formulário, front-end, tinymce

Antes de você ler a descrição abaixo, saiba que procuro um direcionamento, e não que façam o código por mim. Referências de bibliotecas que possam me ajudar, alguma técnica que preciso conhecer.

## O que preciso fazer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para ilustrar o caso, melhor usar uma imagem. Vamos dizer que temos o formulário acima(tinyMCE Editor), e abaixo dele tenho algumas tags. O usuário pode puxar essa tag e colocar no formulário de texto, deixando assim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O usuário poderia puxar a mesma tag quantas vezes quisesse pro formulário, aparecendo mais de uma vez com nomes diferentes: `nome da empresa`,`nome da empresa1`,`nome da empresa2` e por ai vai.

Posteriormente, usando uma linguagem backend, eu precisaria ler essas tags e substituir por um conteúdo do banco de dados, que neste caso é o nome da empresa.

Comment: Não entendi o porque dos negativos, pergunta bem formulada, útil e a respota é bem legal que coisa hein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O trecho abaixo apresenta alguns problemas, como o possicionamento do cursor apos inserir uma tag, dentre outros.

mas basicamente você vai ter que enviar o conteudo da div para o servidor

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
textarea.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  console.log(event);
});

var tags = document.querySelectorAll(".tag");
[].forEach.call(tags, function (tag, indice) {
  tag.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    var novaTag = tag.cloneNode(true);
    var espaco = document.createTextNode("\u00A0");
    textarea.appendChild(novaTag);
    textarea.appendChild(espaco);
  });
});

var enviar = document.getElementById("enviar");
enviar.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var texto = [].map.call(textarea.childNodes, function (node, indice) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3)
      return node.textContent;
    if (node.nodeType == 1)
      return "{" + node.id + "}"
    return "";
  }).join("");
  
  alert(texto);
});
```

```css
#textarea {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  font: medium -moz-fixed;
  font: -webkit-small-control;    
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  resize: both;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}

.tag {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nome_empresa:before {
  content: 'Nome da Empresa';
}

#nome_pessoa:before {
  content: 'Nome da Pessoa';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="tag" id="nome_empresa"></span>
  <span class="tag" id="nome_pessoa"></span>
</div>
<div id="textarea" contenteditable>
</div>
<button id="enviar">Alert(Texto a ser enviado)</button>
```

caso digite `Meu nome é [Nome da Pessoa] e trabalho na [Nome da Empresa]` e clicar para enviar, a string será formatada para `Meu nome é {nome_pessoa} e trabalho na {nome_empresa}`

no lado do servidor poderá usar uma expressão regular... um exemplo com javaScript:

```js
var _tmpl = "Meu nome é {nome_pessoa} e trabalho na {nome_empresa}";
var model = { nome_pessoa: "Toby", nome_empresa: "Contoso S.A." };

var texto = _tmpl.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (str, prop) {
  return model[prop];
});

console.log(texto);
```

Answer (score 3):

Allan, já que você esta utilizando TinyMCE você pode utilizar um recurso dele que são os [Custom toolbar menu button](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-menu-button/).

Dentro do init você pode declarar o setup e utilizar o parametro editor para
inserir na posição escolhida.

**Exemplo:**

```
setup: function(editor) {
     editor.insertContent("Minha Empresa");
}
```

Veja funcionando: http://codepen.io/gabrielr47/pen/yObyNv